# How to quickly switch between displays in fedora 18

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor, display, gnome-shell

I have installed Fedora after using Windows 7. I have two screens connected to my computer: a TV and a 19" monitor.

I only want one screen active at a time.  I'd like to be able to switch which screen is active using a simple mouse-click or keyboard combination.  From the settings window, all I can see is how to clone/extend the screen, which is not what I want to do.

[image]

In Windows 7 when I wanted to switch between connected displays I typed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question that you know that you can toggle monitors on and off using the "on" slider in the "Displays" dialog you show.  This is the standard way of enabling and disabling monitors in Gnome Shell.

---

You can create a quick key combination to toggle your monitors by using this script on [github](https://github.com/PeteMo/toggle/blob/master/toggle.sh) that was designed exactly for this purpose (see [this](http://www.threadstates.com/articles/2009/a-script-for-toggling-display-modes-using-xrandr.html) article for more information).  Copy the script and place it in your home directory.  Make it executable by

```
chmod +x ~/toggle.sh
```

You can then bind this script to a custom keyboard shortcut using the keyboard system settings dialog.  Click on the "Shortcuts" tab and then "Custom Shortcuts" in the left panel.  Click the "+" sign to add a new shortcut and fill in the dialog like so:

[image: Custom Shortcut]

Click "Apply" and then click on the "Disabled" word and press the key combination you want to map to toggling monitors.

Comment: this is what i want, sadly it doesnt work properly..

Comment: Does it work if you just run the script from the command line?

Comment: the script runs but it doesnt do what i wanted. anyway i change it a bit and now it works(one case the tv off and the monitor on and one case just the opposite), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling one of the displays will make the other active by default.

Comment: is it able by a button click?

Comment: A few, yes. Look in the Monitors preferences.

Comment: in 'displays' there isnt preferences.

Comment: See the little slider that says "ON"? It's disabled because the other display is off. Turn that one on and this one off.

Comment: i want to do it by keyboard click

Answer (score 0):

If you go under System -> Preferences -> Monitors you should get to a dialog like this:

[image: ss of monitors dialog]

You can configure your monitor setup through here. I usually check the "Show monitors in panel" and you'll get a little applet in the panel from which you can switch between the monitors.

[image: applet in panel]                                     [image: menu pulled down]

If you have multiple monitors they'll show up in the dialog along with the pulldown in the panel.

Comment: no 'monitor preferences' in fedora 18, and no 'show monitors in panel' on 'displays'